# Problems installing Pycharm

Tags: linux, installation, pycharm, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to install pycharm on my linux OS.
following the instructions pycharm/dowload.
Since I run a linux machine I made sure the pychrarm files in the current directory:

```
ietX220:~$ ls
Desktop pycharm-community-4.0.1
Documents Music
pycharm-community- 4.0.1.tar.gz
Downloads New Folder Templates
Dropbox octave-workspace Videos
examples.desktop Pictures VirtualBox VMs
jdk1.8.0_25 Public Win7-PV2hh-6c3HY-
QJHM9-8RJJH-P86W8.iso

ietX220:~$ pycharm-*.tar.gz
pycharm-community-4.0.1.tar.gz: command not found
```

As you can see the pycharm file is in the current(home) directory but is not found.

Then I opened the tar file made pycharm.sh executable:

```
chmod +x pycharm.sh
```

And then ran:

```
~/pycharm-community-4.0.1/bin$ ./pycharm.sh

Startup Error: Application cannot start in headless mode
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I am having the same issue. It looks like maybe you and I both have a minimal (headless) Java install on our systems. Use your system's method for finding installed packages and search for Java, and i'll bet you find only openjdk-headless

```
yum list installed | grep openjdk
# or on debian-based systems
# dpkg --get-selections | grep openjdk
# =>java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless
```

Solution then is to install the same package without the "-headless" suffix.

Here's where I am getting my information for the solution: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1177379

Comment: This worked well thanks. 
Funny that even Pycharm customer support were not able to pinpoint the problem. 
What I did realize that the Java 1.7 none headless depends on the headless for its operation. 
So correct system setup as following:
   dpkg --get-selections | grep openjdk
   openjdk-7-jre:amd64            install
   openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64   install

Comment: My PyCharm ran normally before, but I dont know why I got similar issue after a few days using it. When I tried running "dpkg --get-selections | grep openjdk openjdk-7-jre:amd64 install openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 install" , the terminal returns: "grep: openjdk-7-jre:amd64: No such file or directory
grep: install: No such file or directory
grep: openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64: No such file or directory
grep: install: No such file or directory
". I still dont know how to resolve this.

Comment: `sudo dnf install java-1.8.0-openjdk` worked for me.

Comment: @mkprz, In my fedora I run this command :
yum list installed | grep openjdk 
and got this o/p 
java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64             1:1.8.0.131-1.b12.fc25          
java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64       1:1.8.0.131-1.b12.fc25            
java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless.x86_64    1:1.8.0.131-1.b12.fc25   

it seems like I have the full version of jdk1.8.0 but stll facing the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and as mentioned before the error was that openjdk was headless. What i did is i installed from the begining openjdk using the command **apt-get install default-jdk** (for ubuntu). I know it's not the best way to do it, however it is rather quick and simple.

Answer (score 2):

If you have already all the prerequisites (such as Java) installed, try out `charmy` (PyCharm installer for Linux).

```
virtualenv charmy-env

source charmy-env/bin/activate

pip install charmy

charmy install
```

That will install PyCharm into your home directory. It will also simplify your feature PyCharm upgrades. To upgrade you would just have to type

```
charmy install
```

instead of downloading distribution manually, unpacking it, etc.

See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/charmy for more.

Answer (score 2):

PYcharm is now available as a snap. Can be easily installed as below

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install snapd
```

Then the community edition can be installed by

```
sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic
```

The classic escape is to get snaps that have been published with classic confinements

Answer (score 1):

220:~$ pycharm-*.tar.gz
    pycharm-community-4.0.1.tar.gz: command not found

gz files are not executable files. I think the current directory is not in your PATH variable. To get around that you would do "./pycharm-community-3.0.1.tar.gz" and you should see the message "Permission denied" as the gz file would not have execute permission. And if you gave it execute permission it would say "cannot execute binary file: Exec format error".

These are the instructions from the JetBrains website:

> ```
> Copy the pycharm-*.tar.gz to the desired installation location
> (make sure you have rw permissions for that directory)
> Unpack the pycharm-*.tar.gz using the following command:
> tar xfz pycharm-*.tar.gz
> Remove the pycharm-*.tar.gz to save disk space (optional)
> Run pycharm.sh from the bin subdirectory
> ```
>
> NOTE: PyCharm on Linux doesn't need special installation or running
>   any installation script. It runs out of the pycharm-*.tar.gz

If you run the command "**tar xfz pycharm-*.tar.gz**" you should end up with a directory in your current directory named "pycharm-community-4.0.3". 
If you **cd pycharm-community-4.0.3/bin**, "ls -al" should show that pycharm.sh is already executable. **Run pycharm.sh** and you should be done. The script will prompt for a password at the end so it can put a startup script in a system directory. You must have admin privileges for that part to work. But if you don't, you can still start PyCharm by executing "**[path to pycharm directory]/bin/pycharm.sh &**"   at the command prompt.

I am not sure what the "NOTE:" is saying, but I would ignore it as you get a working PyCharm by doing what it says above the NOTE: .

Comment: So I downloaded pycharm again. Removed the file from the tarball using Scooter's instructions. Later in the bin directory I wrote:
tX220:~/pycharm-community-4.0.3/bin$ ls
fsnotifier  fsnotifier64  idea.properties  inspect.sh  log.xml  pycharm64.vmoptions  pycharm.png  pycharm.sh  pycharm.vmoptions

tX220:~/pycharm-community-4.0.3/bin$ ./pycharm.sh
Startup Error: Application cannot start in headless mode

Answer (score 1):

Setup the newest stable jdk(like jdk1.7 or jdk 1.8) in your system, and set it is the default jdk.

1.download [JDK8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

2.SET JAVA HOME

```
sudo gedit /etc/environment 

export JAVA_HOME=/home/username/Java/jdk1.8 
export JRE_HOME=/home/username/Java/jdk1.8 
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$JAVA_HOME/lib:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib 


sudo gedit /etc/profile 
//before umask xxx adde
export JAVA_HOME=/home/username/Java/jdk1.8
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$JAVA_HOME/lib:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib 
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin:$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

3. run pycharm

```
./pycharm.sh
```